# Identify the current device in Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I am using ADAL on Android and I access my devices via the Graph API after enrolling them via Intune Company Portal app.

I can obtain the list of devices via

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/registeredDevices
```

Is there a way to somehow identify the current device I used for making the API call and match it to one of the devices from the response?

In Intune Company Portal I can clearly see which device I am currently using. Is this possible using Graph API somehow? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. AFAIK this is not supported at current version of Microsoft Graph. If you require this feature, you can submit the feedback from this [link](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis).

Comment: Ok, too bad. Thanks anyway.Any idea how does Company Intune app does that? Does it use some other (private) API?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with Company In-tune app and doesn't see there is an API can achieve this goal.